# Cruise Control.Net, CVS, and Multiple Modules

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, cvs, ccnet-config

Just starting to use Cruise Control, but can't seem to find anything on this or at least a better approach.  Simple script:

```
<cruisecontrol xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder">
```

Test
  
   
  
  
   cvs.exe
   theRoot
   theModule
   
  ....

Problem is I would like to check more than one module for an update but NOT every module in theRoot.  Something like this:

```
<sourcecontrol type="cvs">
   <executable>cvs.exe</executable>
   <cvsroot>theRoot</cvsroot>
   <module>theModule</module>
   <module>theSecondModule</module>
   <module>theThirdModule</module>
</sourcecontrol>
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your type to "multi" and add sections for each module being tracked

```
<sourcecontrol type="multi">
  <sourceControls>
    <cvs>
       <executable>cvs.exe</executable>
       <!-- Insert other module1 details -->
    </cvs>
    <cvs>
       <executable>cvs.exe</executable>
       <!-- Insert other module2 details -->
    </cvs>
  </sourceControls>
</sourcecontrol>
```

Here's a bit of [documentation](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Multi+Source+Control+Block)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a filtered source control : http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Filtered+Source+Control+Block .
What you describe is a list of inclusionfilters filtered by path.

```
<sourcecontrol type="filtered">
  <sourceControlProvider type="cvs">
    <executable>cvs.exe</executable>
    <project>$/Kunigunda/ServiceLocator</project>
</sourceControlProvider>
<inclusionFilters>
    <pathFilter>
      <pattern>$/Module1/**/*.*</pattern>
    </pathFilter>
    <pathFilter>
      <pattern>$/Module2/**/*.*</pattern>
    </pathFilter>
    <pathFilter>
      <pattern>$/Module3/**/*.*</pattern>
    </pathFilter>
  </inclusionFilters>
</sourcecontrol>
```